# rackup (failed to load command)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

When I type: `bundle exec rackup`it should give some output like this:

```
$ bundle exec rackup
[2017-01-29 21:45:56] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-01-29 21:45:56] INFO ruby 2.4.0 (2016-12-24) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2017-01-29 21:45:56] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=48002 port=9292
```

But instead I get this

```
bundler: failed to load command: rackup (/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rackup)
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all

« truncated »
```

Here is my gem file:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"

gem 'rspec', '~> 3.6.0.beta2'
gem 'coderay', '~> 1.1', '>= 1.1.1'
gem 'rack-test', '~> 0.6.3'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.8'
```

Any idea what the problem might be? I am stuck on this for quiet a while.

Comment: It’s not the gems you have installed that’s imortant, it’s the gems you have in your `Gemfile`. What does your `Gemfile` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

In the `config.ru` file I defined a `rackup` config file but didn't delete the old one.

So

```
require_relative 'config/environment'
require_relative 'app/api.rb'

run Rails.application
run ExpenseTracker::API.new
```

Became

```
require_relative 'app/api.rb'

run ExpenseTracker::API.new
```