# Heroku: failed to load command: rackup (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rackup)

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm trying to run an app on Heroku but it seems to error out towards the end. What my app does is basically grab videos from a Youtube channel and the number of comments that video has. Everything works well up until the end where I'm about to return the info to another website. This is the error I'm receiving:

```
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593081+00:00 app[web.1]:===================VIDEO=================
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593082+00:00 app[web.1]: Num Comments: 5
bundler: failed to load command: rackup 
(/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rackup)
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593101+00:00 app[web.1]: SignalException: SIGTERM
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593102+00:00 app[web.1]:
    /app/vendor/ruby- 2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:171:in `select'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593102+00:00 app[web.1]:
  /app/vendor/ruby- 2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:171:in `block in start'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593103+00:00 app[web.1]:
    /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593104+00:00 app[web.1]:
    /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/webrick/server.rb:158:in `start'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593105+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-
2.0.3/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593105+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-
2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:297:in `start'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593106+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-
2.0.3/lib/rack/server.rb:148:in `start'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593107+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.3/bin/rackup:4:in `<top 
(required)>'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593108+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rackup:22:in `load'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.593108+00:00 app[web.1]:   
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/bin/rackup:22:in `<top (required)>'
2017-06-29T22:27:49.792129+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with 
status 1
```

I'm not sure this is happening since it works locally when I use ngrok but any insight would be appreciated! Here is my `config.ru` in case it helps

```
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require

require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/app')

run YoutubeIntegration
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rackup (failed to load command)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558890/rackup-failed-to-load-command)

Comment: @KickButtowski already looked at that link but it seems to be a different issue since it's describing a different error. That link has an issue of `LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails/all` whereas mine is `SignalException: SIGTERM`

Comment: Unfortunately I have this error as well and have been completely unable to solve it.